# How do I use a template engine in Yii?

Tags: php, yii2, twig, smarty, template-engine

I want to write a program with Yii so that users can have their template.

My solution is that every user has a record in a DB to keep a customized template like HTML code and some syntax like Smarty or Twig.

How can I use PHP to get that records and just print it on the screen and my template engine extracts syntax and shows best results? Is that possible or not? How should I do this?

Really you know if you save php codes in database, when you print them into a file, php codes you saved in database don't run. 
For me the most important thing is that to save template in database whit php commands and then echo them in a file and php code run same usually.

But is is important to use smarty or twig and don't let users add php codes directly.

Comment: Please explain what the expected results with some more details. It's hard toget what you are trying to achieve,

Comment: I edit my question. Thanks

Comment: If possible, don't let your users write their own php code. This lets your users do anything on your system with whatever privileges your php interpreter runs, and that's a major security breach. For that matter, don't let them write HTML code either. For most tasks, markdown is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. 
Just save every thing in database and when load them use eval()  function. 
See documents in php and w3school.

Answer (score 1):

For user interface templates you can use different layouts in Yii. Just put your different layout templates in the `./views/layouts` folder:

```
./views/layouts/main-template-1.php
./views/layouts/main-template-2.php
./views/layouts/main-template-3.php
```

and select the layout in the controller when executing an action depending on the user which should be known in the controller.

EDIT: Without uploading layout files from users you can load the template code from the database (HTML skeleton) and then in the Controller put together layout and view code:

```
$contentWithoutLayout = $this->renderPartial('myview',...);
return $this->applyLayout(contentWithoutLayout, $layoutFromDb);
```

where `applyLayout()` is your method to merge layout and view content.

Comment: Yes i know this but i don't want let users to upload files and i need to let users to customize their template.